# How to reverse order of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, reverse

I have this div-container:

```
<div id="game_rating">
    <span class="rating_star">
        <img src="../images/star.png">
    </span>

    <span class="rating_star">
        <img src="../images/star.png">
    </span>

    <span class="rating_star">
        <img src="../images/star_half.png">
    </span>

    <span class="rating_star">
        <img src="../images/star_empty.png">
    </span>

    <span class="rating_star">
        <img src="../images/star_empty.png">
    </span>
</div>
```

Now I want to reverse the order of the spans with the class "rating_star" so it looks like this:

```
star_empty.png
star_empty.png
star_half.png
star.png
star.png
```

How can I achieve this with JavaScript / jQuery (must work in old browsers like IE8, too)?

Comment: It looks as there are only two different images: star_empty and star. Would it be good enough to swap the first and the last?

Comment: Nope. I just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appending and prepending moves the elements in the DOM, so just iterate from top to bottom and prepend the spans, and the order will be reversed.

```
$.each($('#game_rating > span'), function() {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8a6u/3/)

or with `Array.reverse()`

```
$('#game_rating').append($('#game_rating > span').get().reverse());
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8a6u/4/)

Without jQuery

```
var game  = document.getElementById('game_rating');
var spans = game.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i=spans.length; i--;) {
    game.appendChild(spans[i]);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f8a6u/6/)

Comment: Can you provide a Javascript only solution (without jQuery)? I just ask because in my case it would be better...

Comment: @drpelz - sure, give me a sec!

Comment: The strange thing is I get "'null' is not an object (evaluating 'game.getElementsByTagName')".

Comment: Does the ID match, is the ID really `game_rating`? Double check it, and make sure you don't have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: @drpelz - Oh, and when using this, add the script **at the bottom**, right before the `</body>` tag, otherwise you'll get that error.

Answer (score 2):

do this like:

```
$("#game_rating").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children().each(function(){
        $this.prepend(this);
    });
});
```

or you can even create a general jQuery function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.reverseNodes = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.children().each(function(){
            $this.prepend(this);
        });
    });
};
$('#game_rating').reverseNodes();
```

and this is the working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RcXcr/).

Comment: @adeneo: I created the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RcXcr/) just for you my fellow coder :)

Comment: As i said, I only tested it before the edit, and it didn't work as you where targeting the spans in the first loop, and then iterating the children in the next loop, but still, why two loops ?

Answer (score 1):

maybe with jquery:

```
var parent = $('#game_rating');
var spans = parent.children('span');
parent.append(spans.get().reverse());
```

Comment: I get this error message: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'parent.children')